# provide a flash version for specific ie version otherwse provide a js version

Tags: javascript

I created a animation banner with a flash and a js version.

Is it possible to detect a ie version lower than say version 9, then to provide a flash banner otherwise a js banner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional comments to detect IE versions

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

E.g. you can put any content inside this comment and it will only show for browsers lower then IE 9

```
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]> <script src="doOldIEstuff.js"></script> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: could I put the conditional comments within body tag ?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, you can put them anywhere.